# Python Mutable Objects and when to copy them

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion, mutable

I have a json-like dictionary containing other dictionaries and lists like so:

```
        "A": {
            "attrib2": "bar", 
            "attrib1": "foo", 
            "B": "b", 
            "C": [
                "c1", 
                "c2"
            ], 
            "D": [
                {
                    "attrib3": "baz"
                }, 
                {
                    "attrib4": "muh"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Each value can be a list (of dictonaries or values), a dictionary or an immutable value (like "c1" or 5).

Now I want to search for specific values that I reference by the keys needed to get to them (["A", "B"] would point to the value "b"). Since there could be lists in the given path of keys I am returning all found values. My function looks like this:

```
def getValues(inputDict, keyList):
    """
        works on dicts in json-like format as outputted by complexXmlElement2dict
    """
    values = list()
    if keyList:
        key = keyList.pop(0)
        try:
            currentValue = inputDict[key]
        except KeyError:
            logger.debug("could not find key {}".format(key))
            return list()

        if isinstance(currentValue, dict):
            additionalValues = getValues(copy.deepcopy(currentValue), list(keyList))  # copy list and dict!!
            values.extend(additionalValues)

        elif isinstance(currentValue, list):
            for subDict in currentValue:
                assert isinstance(subDict, dict)
                values.extend(getValues(copy.deepcopy(subDict), list(keyList)))  # copy list and dict!!
        else:
            values.append(currentValue)

    return list(values)
```

As you can see, I am somewhat paranoid about the mutable objects used here. I am copying the list of keys that are left to find the correct values and also the dictionary that I am using every single time. My function works as expected, but I think I am creating massive overhead by unnecessarily copying all those objects.

When can I leave out copying the dictionaries and lists in this example and why? Trial-and-error is no option because I don't have all possible input dictionaries and also because I want to gain a better understanding. I should add that I have read lots of examples and explanations of mutable objects in python and although I think I understand the concept I don't feel comfortable enough leave out what I think is unnecessary because others rely on the correctness of this code.

```
getValues(copy.deepcopy(currentValue), list(keyList))
getValues(copy.deepcopy(subDict), list(keyList)))
return list(values)
```

I am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any reason to copy dictionary or list. You are not updating any of them. You are just extracting data from them. So just pass the reference in recursive function.

Comment: My keyList is updated every time I go one level deeper: key = keyList.pop(0) and my values list is updated every time I find a value that matches the search pattern. The dictionary currentValue also points to a different part of the big dictionary every time.

Comment: About keylist, you can pass same list everytime and pass index to identify which key to be processed. About dictionary currentValue, it doesn't matter if it points to a different big dictionary, if you are not updating it you can use shallow copy. No need to deep copy. About value list, you are always creating a new list, appending it into the previous one. You need to understand the concept of recursive functions.